# Why cannot the permutation $f^{-1}(1,2,3,5)f$ be even

Tags: group-theory, permutations

Please help me to prove that if $f\in S_6$ be arbiotrary permutation so the permutation $f^{-1}(1,2,3,5)f$ cannot be an even permutation.

I am sure there is a small thing I am missing it. Thank you.

Comment: The sign function is a homomorphism to $C_2$ which is abelian and hence...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: The sign of a product of permutations is the product of the signs, and the sign of $f$ is the same as the sign of $f^{-1}$.(If we are given a representation of $f$ as a product of disjoint cycles, how can we write $f^{-1}$?)

Note also that there is a more general result stating that for any two permutations $\sigma, \tau$,both $\tau^{-1}\sigma\tau$ and $\sigma$ have the same cycle type. It then immediately follows that they have the same sign.

Comment: Good hint. I gave the same patterns. ;-) and +1

Comment: I got that point.

Comment: @Basil R So then $\operatorname{Sign}(f^{-1}\sigma f) =\dots$? (There is a result here that is true for any permutation $\sigma$, not just $(12345)$

Comment: @TomOldfield, $\operatorname{sign}(f^{-1} \sigma f) = 2 \operatorname{sign} f + \operatorname{sign} \sigma = \operatorname{sign} \sigma$ (if you take everything modulo 2).

Answer (score 3):

I think, you can do the problem, if you know that:

> $f$ is even so is $f^{-1}$ and $f$ is odd so is $f^{-1}$.

Comment: Merci Babk S. for it.